# How to create a SAP Fiori Custom Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I want to create a Fiori launchpad that is able to run `Fiori` applications that **are not developed** with `stand alone` option. But I can not find any option inside of the WEB IDE for creating a Fiori launchpad application while as I understand `SAP Fiori` is a SAPUI5 application itself.

Any document or link is appreciated.

Comment: Finally I found a good [repository](https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate) for serving OData based on JPA and I had extended it for implementing a custom launchpad for OpenUI5. You can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/mjza/openui5_custom_launchpad). I made it as an answer, but some moderator who has no idea about UI5, deleted my answer. You can extend my sample launchpad freely.

Comment: https://github.com/mjza/openui5_custom_launchpad

Answer (score 4):

A Fiori launchpad is basically a collection of tiles, so you want to try that route.

The most basic approach seems to be a tile-based Grid layout: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.GridTiles/preview

Or you can use a sap.m.TileContainer with sap.m.StandardTiles:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview

Or you can use some sap.m.Panels. Give each panel a title and fill it with sap.m.GenericTiles and it should look very similar to an actual launchpad:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.GenericTileAsLaunchTile/preview

The real launchpad is made of stuff from the `sap.ushell.ui.launchpad` namespace which is not very well documented, but you might want to re-engineer that as well.

Comment: Dear @Marc, Thanks for the links. They are definitely helpful, but my current problem is routing. As I understand the standard launchpad loads the data of different applications inside of the shell. The problem is that I create different applications in different projects and deploy them to different packages inside of the ABAP repository. Now the questions is how can I route to those views as it does in standard launchpad.